# Way of resolving a specific type of merge conflict automatically by a custom rule

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, package.json

I work on the application that always updates the `"version"` field in the `package.json` file along with my commit and thus causes a merge conflict on every single git auto merge.

```js
<<<<<<< HEAD (Current change)
  "version": "1.0.1-63078a50.0",
=======
  "version": "1.0.1-63077bc0.0",
>>>>>>> COMMIT_ID (Incoming change)
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
```

Is there way like writing a kind of script or so to always accept the `Current change` only for this specific conflict?

Comment: Of course there is: you write the script and then you run the script. Writing the script is the hard part. You might find it easier to write a custom *merge driver*, but even then, you still have to write some code. I'll note that it's probably wiser not to store the version like that, in a file that's otherwise "regular source". Store it *separately* in a generated file that doesn't get committed and you won't need to do this at all.

Comment: @torek thanks for your comment! It is used in the cicd to set the application version with the command `node -p "require('./package.json').version"`. But if I store this version separately which is not committed, can I keep this version sharable and auto-updated accross other team members?

Comment: `1.0.1-63077bc0.0` looks like modified output from `git describe`. What I might do is store the semantic-version <major,minor> numbers in some tracked file, the patch version being autogenerated and/or maybe in that same file, and the `git describe` output generated during the build but not stored *anywhere*. You'd get the full string by putting the pieces together. The precise details will depend on both the language you're using and the build system (with the build system perhaps depending on the languages).